# Resultado é sempre 404, mas os registros existem. Onde pode estar o erro?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`POST /sinalizar_interesse/9/3/` significa que 9 está interessado(a) em 3.

Código:

```py
    def localiza_id(id_usuario):
        for pess in database['PESSOA']:
            if pess['id'] == id_usuario:
                return 200
        return 404
    @app.route('/sinalizar_interesse/<int:id_interessada>/<int:id_alvo>', methods=['POST'])
    def sinalizar_interesse(id_interessada, id_alvo):
        pessoa_busca = (id_interessada)
        pessoa_alvo = (id_alvo)
        if (localiza_id(pessoa_busca) or localiza_id(pessoa_alvo)) == 404:
            return 404
        if (localiza_id(pessoa_busca) and localiza_id(pessoa_alvo)) == 200:
            return 200
```

Está dando erro nesses testes. Deveria dar o código 200, mas independente do teste ele retorna 404.
Não entendo o que está de errado, não sei se é o método pois está usando método `POST` e os teste usam o método `PUT` e não estou conseguindo obter o código 200.

Testes:

```py
        #agora posso marcar interesse de 3 pra 9 e de 9 pra 3 sem problemas
        r = requests.put('http://localhost:5003/sinalizar_interesse/9/3/')
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code,200)
        r = requests.put('http://localhost:5003/sinalizar_interesse/3/9/')
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code,200)
```

Comment: O link http://localhost:5003//sinalizar_interesse/9/3/ não implica em nada no entendimento da pergunta... localhost é um ambiente na sua máquina, só você consegue acessar....

Comment: Leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/447033/interesse-tinder-localhost#comment858395_447033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não conheço Python, mas ao olhar para o seu código é possível ver que há um problema na sua lógica.

O endpoint com `put` não existe (vc testa com `put`, mas o endpoint criado é com `post`. Neste caso, pode ser usado qualquer um dos verbos, desde que entenda a diferença entre eles. O que vai mudar é a semântica que vc pretende.

O ponto acima pode não ser o problema de fato, pois, dependendo da linguagem/framework pode funcionar, mas recomendava a mudança para que o seu código fique coerente.

O que de gato está incorreto na lógica é a comparação do resultado da busca das pessoas. Repare que vc faz "pessoa busca" `OU` "pessoa alvo" e compara esse resultado com 404. O mesmo logo abaixo, usando `E` e 200. Para corrigir está parte, compare AMBOS os resultados com 404 ou 200.

Exemplo: `if (localiza_id(pessoa_busca) or localiza_id(pessoa_alvo)) == 404:` deveria ser `if localiza_id(pessoa_busca) == 404 or localiza_id(pessoa_alvo) == 404:`.

Comment: Ainda há coisas que podem ser melhoradas no código, mas estou no celular e procurei indicar somente o que parece ser crítico. Mais tarde adiciono algumas sugestões.